# Open Facebook app using Facebook link page with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

After several searches on Google and Stackoverflow, I can't find the solution to my problem.

At present, my app opens a Facebook page via Safari. But I would like this same page to open automatically in the Facebook app. Would you have a solution to offer me please?

Here is the code that I implemented but the Facebook app does not open ...

```
@IBAction func facebookButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if let appURL = URL(string: "facebook://") {

        let canOpen = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL)
        print("\(canOpen)")

        let appName = "Facebook"
        let appScheme = "\(appName)://"
        let appSchemeURL = URL(string: appScheme)

        if

            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSchemeURL! as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appSchemeURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        } else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\(appName) Erreur !", message: "L'application \(appName) ne peut pas s'ouvrir. Merci de l'installer depuis l'App Store.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added facebook scheme to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist?

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>facebook sceheme here</string>
</array>
```